# Why are my images saved in Photoshop CS3 so large?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have taken a screen capture, pasted it into a "new" image in CS3 and cropped it down to 800 X 522 pixels.  What I can't figure out is why the hell I can't get it under a 2 Mb file on my computer.  Even when I save it at as level 3 JPEG it's still over 2 Mb.  The file size is what I'm seeing in my documents folder.  Photoshop insists its a 3.8 Mb file!!! Hell even the pixel dimensions suggests its only 1.19 Mb.  What is going on?

Comment: Off-topic I'm afraid - the Graphic Design SE might be a better place.

Comment: 'I have taken a screen capture' are you using any other tool for this or doing just default  print screen?

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce your results by following your steps, are you sure you are resizing the image and not just the canvas? Photoshop also shows a different "space" usage when working with images. It shows the amount of memory being used and not the actual file size on disk.

Here are the steps I took and the results I found

1. Take Screenshot
2. New image
3. Saved image (quality 12 - file size 534kB)
4. Image->image size
5. Provide new size
6. Saved new image (quality - file size 224kB)

Comment: I know, as I said to my wife yesterday I only have technology problems that no one understands but thanks for trying.  The "Save for Web & Devices" at least works properly.

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't provide you with the solution you required

Answer (score 0):

2Mb sounds about right for a Photoshop PSD file of that size, but not for a JPEG. I've just reproduced the same thing in CS3 (on Windows 7) and I'm getting a JPG around 60Kb in size, depending on the contents of the image. Here's exactly what I'm doing:

1. Take a full screen shot and copy to the clipboard.
2. Start Photoshop CS3. *File > New...* to create a new image. Accept the default image settings: the dimensions should be set to the size of the clipboard contents.
3. *Edit > Paste* to paste the screenshot in as a new layer.
4. Use the crop tool to crop to the approximate dimensions you specified (in fact, mine is a little bigger: 912 x 557px).
5. *File > Save for Web & Devices...* to export as a JPEG with the required settings. (I'm choosing JPEG, Very High quality, Progressive).

The JPEG comes out around **60Kb** in size. If I drop the JPEG quality to Medium (30), the size drops to around **13Kb**. If I choose *File > Save...* and choose a level 3 JPEG, it's about **33Kb**. And as a PSD, it's around **2Mb**.

I can't see why your JPEG would be coming out so big. I wondered if you were doing *File > Save...* and saving as a PSD but with a .jpg filename, but your comment about saving as a level 3 JPEG would suggest that's not the case.

Comment: I just tried the "Save for Web & Devices" and it worked properly but I tried a standard "Save As" to jpeg and it still gives me a 3.8 Mb file for some freakin reason.  Anyways, at least I can move on with this work around.  Thanks

Comment: Glad to help, Phil. That *Save* behaviour is weird though. Don't mean to insult you with stupid suggestions, but in the Save dialog you're definitely setting the format to JPEG rather than just setting the filename? Could you upload the resulting JPEG somewhere for us to have a look at?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the issue isn't reproducible by other folks, I'd guess you need to reset your Photoshop preferences. That's generally the next thing to try if closing and reopening PS doesn't clear some weird glitch.

In case you're not familiar: hold down Ctl-Alt-Shift/Cmd-Opt-Shift while the program is starting to get the "Delete Preferences" dialog. It won't toast your custom kbsc's or workspaces, but it will reset your recently used files, character settings, etc. to defaults.